# Very slow queries selecting @@ session variables.

Tags: mysql, atlassian

We're running locally managed databases for our Atlassian suite (Jira/Confluence/Fisheye).   I noticed something strange in the slow query logs.  There are a bunch of selects of session variables showing up like

```
# Schema: fisheyedb  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 2.487396  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 90  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
# QC_Hit: No  Full_scan: No  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0
# No InnoDB statistics available for this query
use fisheyedb;
SET timestamp=1511794875;
SELECT @@session.tx_isolation;
```

We have the slow query time threshold set to 2 seconds.

They're so prevelant that they're the number 1 entry in our daily pt-query -digest archives

```
# Query 1: 0.08 QPS, 0.22x concurrency, ID 0x30AAEC10BC3D0C37 at byte 7953939
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 0.33
# Time range: 2017-11-27 09:01:15 to 2017-11-28 00:11:48
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count         25    4120
# Exec time     19  11926s      2s     14s      3s      5s   972ms      3s
# Lock time      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Rows sent      0   4.02k       1       1       1       1       0       1
# Rows examine   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Rows affecte   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Bytes sent     0 362.12k      90      91   90.00   88.31       0   88.31
# Merge passes   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp tables     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp disk tbl   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp tbl size   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     2 116.68k      29      29      29      29       0      29
# String:
# Databases    fisheyedb (4105/99%), confluence... (15/0%)
# Hosts        x.x.x.x
# Last errno   0
# Users        fisheyeuse... (4105/99%), confluence... (15/0%)
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms
#    1s  ################################################################
#  10s+  #
# EXPLAIN /*!50100 PARTITIONS*/
SELECT @@session.tx_isolation\G
```

What can cause reading a simple session variable like tx_isolation to be anything less than instantaneous?

Answer (score 0):

- Sometimes things like this happen because of other things going on at the same time.  Can you spot such in the slowlog?
- The probably will *probably* be solved in version 8.0, when a number of things get turned into real InnoDB tables.
- Some 3rd party products issue an awful number of seemingly spurious and redundant information queries.  Let's see the output from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Com%';`
- Set `long_query_time = 0.1` and see if you catch a lot more of these queries, plus other things.